# What would be a good schema to classify objects based on a hierarchy

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

I have a list of videos which I would like to classify in a hierarchy

```
category (id, name, parent)
video (id, name)
video_category (id, video_id, category_id)
```

my categories would look like this

```
/A/B/C/[C1, C2]
/D/E/F/[D1, D2]
```

So if my video is categorized as follows

```
v1 categorized as C1
v2 categorized as C2

If I view underneath "C" it should show me both videos.
```

Is this an appropriate design?

Comment: Is it just a two-level heirarchy or is it more? No limit even? You might want to take extra care to make sure you for instance can select all videos under category C (which might be C+C_1+C_2+C_1_1 etc)

Comment: its not a 2 level hierarchy, definitely multi level and the behavior for "C" will be the same as you have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is pretty good, with some small comments and one big but.

The small comments:

- video_category doesn't need an id, its columns form a unique composite primary key already.  Adding an extra id here allows you to store duplicate data.
- Try to avoid using 'id' as a column; call the id column in the video table 'video_id' so it's easier to remember which columns in other tables you can join it on (this becomes more and more useful the bigger and more complex your schema becomes)

The big but is *but MySQL doesn't support connect by prior*, which is a problem as this is the most intuitive way to traverse trees like this.  There are ways round it, either by implementing a more complicated schema, or by structuring your tree traversal procedures iteratively instead of recursively.  You may find the links in the following useful:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,38047,38089#msg-38089